# PHP use result of as variable

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Is it possible to use the result of an if with an OR statement as a variable for a function?

As example:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;

if ($a || $b) {
     $this->functionCall($a)
}
```

Other example:

```
$a = false;
$b = true;

if ($a || $b) {
    $this->functionCall($b)
}
```

Third and final exmaple:

```
$a = true;
$b = true;

if ($a || $b) {
    $this->functionCall($a, $b)
}
```

So I need to detect what variable is true and pass it as a paramater. Is this even possible?

Any helps is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Something wrong with standard `if() { } else if() { } else { }` syntax?

Comment: In your first and second example, the value you pass to the function is `true`, does it really matter whether it's `$a` or `$b` ?

Comment: @roberto06 yeah it does :)

Comment: Simple solution: pass __both__ variables

Answer (score 3):

I'd do the logic bit inside a two-parameter function if I were you, as such :

```
function myFunc($a = false, $b = false) {
    if ($a == true)
        echo 'a';
    if ($b == true)
        echo 'b';
}

myFunc(); // echoes nothing

$a = true;
$b = false;
myFunc($a, $b); // echoes 'a'

$a = false;
$b = true;
myFunc($a, $b); // echoes 'b'

$a = true;
$b = true;
myFunc($a, $b); // echoes 'ab'
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.6+ version, filter out the falsely values (you can pass a callback to array_filter for different checks) and use those with the splat operator.

```
$params = array_filter([$a, $b]);
$this->callFunction(...$params);
```

No need for any IF checks and confusing in IF assignments.

Explore [Variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and Argument unpacking.

Comment: Note, you'll need the correct number of params in your callFunction, again you could use `function callFunction(...$params){}` and examine the params array.